How to auto move GtkWindow on current focused workspace?
I'm trying to automatically move the window to the focused workspace. That is, when I change the workspace, the Gtkwindow will automatically move to that workspace. I tried the script below but it is not working. Can anybody check it?
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/x11/gdkx.h>

int update (gpointer user_data){
    printf ("Timer\n");

    GtkNative *native = gtk_widget_get_native ((GtkWidget* )user_data);
    GdkSurface *surface = gtk_native_get_surface ((GtkNative *)native);

    //current desktop id
    guint32 desktopId = gdk_x11_surface_get_desktop (surface);
    printf ("Desktop Id %d\n", desktopId);

    gdk_x11_surface_move_to_current_desktop ((GdkSurface*)surface);
    //gdk_x11_surface_move_to_desktop (( GdkSurface *)surface, desktopId);
}


static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "ColorPicker");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 415, 300);
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));

  g_timeout_add(512, (GSourceFunc)update, window);
  gtk_widget_show (window);
}


int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE); 
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}


It's unlikely that you'll be able to do this using GTK/GDK, window position control has been fully delegated to the window manager/composer in GTK4, even using X11. To do what you want, the way forward is to write an extension for gnome-shell.
